# Why does my code stuck after speak function?

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

I try to create a Voice Assistant on python3

This is my function **Speak** (with pyttsx):

```
def speak(what):
    print("Gosha: " + what)
    speak_engine.say( what )
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()
```

in the main body it works fine, but in function **execute_cmd**, after **Speak** function my code stucks.
One part of **execute_cmd**:

```
def execute_cmd(cmd, voice):
    global finished
    finished = False
    #import debug
    if cmd == 'ctime':
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        hours = str(now.hour)
        minutes = str(now.minute)
        if (now.minute < 10): minutes = '0' + minutes
        speak("Now " + hours + ":" + minutes)
        finished = True
```

**finished** will never **True**

This happens anywhere in the function

pls help me

(sorry for my eng, I'm from Russia)

UPD: I debugged my code and noticed, my code get stuck on **speak_engine.runAndWait()**

I know, many people have same problem, but their solutions didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you problem. What exactly do you mean by your code getting "Stuck"? Since you said that your `finished` variable will never be `False`, I assume that the code runs through and doesn't get stuck. My best guess is that your code simply doesn't produce sound.

If that's the case, I could imagine it's due to the previous loop still being active. So maybe try adding the following to your speak() function:

```
ef speak(what):
    print("Gosha: " + what)
    try:
        speak_engine.endLoop()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    speak_engine.say( what )
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reply to you. I have a mistake, **False will never True**.